# Bands of background color show when painting image as it is uncovered

Tags: user-interface, graphics, wxwidgets

I have a wxWidgets C++ app that displays an image. When the image is obscured by another window, and I drag that other window very slowly to uncover the image, the image frequently shows bands of background color that did not get painted.

The image is in a bitmap, and is rendered in a scrolling pane. The OnPaint function is as simple as possible. The behavior is the same whether I use true or false as the last parameter to DrawBitmap ("use_mask").

```
void OnPaint(wxPaintEvent &) {
    wxPaintDC dc(this);
    PrepareDC(dc);
    dc.DrawBitmap(bitmap, 0,0, false);
}
```

I tried using wxBufferedPaintDC. The problem remained. What can I do about this?

In the picture below, I have just dragged the Firefox window slowly to the right,
 revealing my app's picture.

[image: vertical stripe is bogus]

I am testing this on Windows 7, service pack 1. AMD A6-3620 APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics 2.2 GHz. VC++ 2012. wxWidgets 2.9.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in version 2.9.4. It was not present in the previous stable build, 2.8.12. It appears to affect only scrolled windows.

The best solution at present is probably to use build 2.8.12. If that is not practical, you can work around the problem by painting the whole image using a wxClientDC. It is best to do it only occasionally. I came up with a heuristic for determining when a stripe was probably missed. It is based on keeping a recent history of the update regions. It gets false-positives, but not so many as to cause flicker, at least on my machine.

I will post more when I know more.

UPDATE Eric Jensen reports that another workaround is to override the OnDraw method to do painting, and not use an on-paint handler at all.

UPDATE Problem does not manifest itself when using Windows Aero themes.

FIXED - http://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/14757

Answer (score 1):

Disable erase background event. When wxWidgets wants to update the display it emits two events: an erase background event and a paint event. You must implement an empty method for the erase background event (in other words: intercept the EVT_ERASE_BACKGROUND event and dont call event.Skip()).

Since your bitmap covers the entire panel, you do not need to erase the background.

The reason using wxClientDC works for you is because "Using wxPaintDC within your EVT_PAINT() handler automatically sets the clipping area to the damaged area of the window. Attempts to draw outside this area do not appear."

Since there is a problem with the clipping area, ignoring the clipping area 'solves' the problem.

This is covered in the detailed description section of the wxPaintDC and wxClientDC class reference docs.

---

Here is a sketch of a 'better' answer.  This is a lot more complex that your timer and redraw all solution, but it is better in the sense that it is much more frugal with system resources and so your application will become more responsive.

Two things are needed.

1. A faster way of getting your bitmap displayed
2. Only redraw the damaged area of your bitmap.

( Note: Using DrawBitmap on wxPaintDC actually process the entire bitmap, and then clips the output )

To speed up the display of parts of your bitmap, you need to draw the bitmap into a memory DC and keep this handy somewhere ( this solution is NOT frugal with memory, but that isn;'t usually a problem with modern computers ) so that you can blit the parts of it you need into the wxPaintDC.

```
wxMemoryDC memdc;
memdc.SelectObject(bitmap);
dc.Blit( ...
```

Here's the description of the Blit parameters http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8/wx_wxdc.html#wxdcblit

To process just the damaged areas, you need to call GetUpdateRegion and work though the reutun with a region iterator.  I see you are using a scrolled panel, so you will have to allow for that, since   the update regions are in terms of the client area in the window, not the logical area in your bitmap .

```
 wxRegionIterator upd(GetUpdateRegion());
 while ( upd )
 {  wxRect rect(upd,GetRect());
    // calculate damaged rectangle in terms of your complete bitmap
    ...
    // blit the calculated rectangle from bitmap in memoryDC to damaged recatngle in wxPaintDC
    ...

    upd++;
 {
```

Comment: Oops. That broke the app. Some of the background is sometimes exposed. It must be cleared. I will try painting it with a brush in  OnEraseBackground or OnPaint.

Comment: Oh darn. I removed the UPDATE part of the answer because I found that using a ClientDC caused a lot of flicker. Our edits crossed paths. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Thanks for that. I regret to say it will not work. I have determined that the defect is in the update regions themselves. They are being painted correctly. Occasionally either one is too small, or one gets lost somehow. I took it to the wxWidgets forums. Read all about it. http://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=36011

Comment: You seem to be knowledgeable about the inner workings of wx. How does it come up with those update regions? Does it obtain them from the Windows native calls or events directly, or does it calculate them somehow? (It is a puzzlement to me why wx does not just use CPaintDC from Windows.) If you could point me to where to look in the wx source code, that would be appreciated. I tried stepping into it with the debugger, but was soon lost and dazed.

Comment: The reason the updates are "wrong" is that your paint handler is taking too long.  You can see this happening in any app if you add a sleep to the paint handler.  The solution is to optimize your paint handler.

Comment: I have not tried the second proposed workaround. My assumption, perhaps a faulty one, was that since the update regions are bad, using them to redraw the image would not work. But I think what you are implying is that if I do the memDC trick, the update regions will heal themselves.

Comment: What I had already done before you updated your answer was to put code into the on-paint handler that inspects the update regions, and when it finds a gap, does a full repaint. That works just fine. I am not happy with it of course. The "image" program that comes with wxWidgets does the same thing on my machine, BTW. I do not know why things would be slow on this machine. It is a brand new Gateway with 4 fast processors and all the trimmings. Something about cache hits maybe. But it's good that I found the problem rather than a customer. I will try the memDC thing, probably tomorrow.

Comment: If your paint handler sits around too long twiddling pixels then the stream of paint events gets jammed up and some get discarded, so leaving bare patches in your image.  Test this theory: add a call to sleep ( better: a CPU hogging loop ), vary the duration, and see if the problem gets worse.

Comment: I know that the most likely scenario is that some software is losing (discarding) an update region occasionally. There is no justification for that, no matter how slow the program might be. The total number cannot exceed a few hundred. It could keep those in memory and wait a decade for the program to catch up. In actuality it sometimes fails after less than 10. Also the problem seems worst when I move the obscuring window very slowly. If it is Windows that's doing it, well, that's that. The only programs I have come across that do that on this machine are built with wxWidgets. Open source.

Comment: The other possibility, besides dropping an update region, is that a region is calculated too small. Again, by far the most likely place that could be happening is in the wxWidgets code. Although I have a workaround, I hate to give up without knowing what and where the problem lies. It's been like that since my first programming job on an IBM 360 in 1971. I am actually poking through the wxWidgets source code now.

Comment: Well, for it is worth I worked on IBM 370s in the mid 70s.  But I prefer an experimental approach.  I have suggested a simple test of my theory - why not try it?

Comment: The reason I am luke-warm on implementing the memDC is that I already have a workaround that performs very well. Now it is just a challenge to figure out why there is a problem in the first place, and perhaps submit a patch to the wxWidgets project.

Comment: It turns out to be a new bug in 2.9.4. In 2.8.12 I can put a one-second delay into the OnPaint handler, and it mops up the background just fine. There is a ticket in the bug-tracker, and the wxWindows gurus are in hot pursuit. Discussion in the wx-dev mailing list.